# PubNub PHP SDK encountering class error when installing and configuring (Use case real-time map)

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, pubnub

Hello guys I am trying to get pubnub PHP SDK to work. Followed the guide on https://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/pubnub-php-sdk but I kept encountering the following issue:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Pubnub\Pubnub'. Can anyone assist me on it.

P.S. 
I am intending to build a map that tracks assets in real-time but the resources that I was given for this project is extremely limited in scope and after reading pubnub documentation and guide it seems viable but since I am currently encountering unexpected error, I am wondering is it possible that there is alternative solution for asset tracking in real-time? My understanding is that

1. Asset has to output longitude and latitude
2. Data will goes through a stream processor
3. Stream Processor output and store the data
4. Front End Map will display the location

I am using MySQL, CPANEL (Non-root user), prototype is build using web technologies JS,HTML5 CSS3 and wrapped using cordova.

Comment: What is your question? "Uncaught Error" is (at least for me) not enough information

Comment: The "thing" that is emitting the location is likely a mobile device, right? So you would be using iOS or Android PubNub SDK to emit it. Or are you using device like RaspberryPi or Arduino and using PHP on it? The issue you are having though sounds like development environment configuration issue. [PubNub EON framework](https://github.com/pubnub/eon-map) is a great solution for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for all your feedback! I manage to find an alternate API (Pusher) that works (It has proper documentation too)